# Bulk Insertion of data from a file to Ms Access using OLEDB

Tags: ms-access-2007, oledb, bulkinsert

How can I insert bulk data from an Excel file to Ms Access data base using OLEDB connection without using loops? I'm using OLEDB connection in a C# windows application.